# How to solve this error in Xcode when testing your app on the Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I've tested my Apple Watch app on the simulator and it runs perfectly...However I couldn't test my app on the actual Apple Watch device:

I ran my iPhone app in Xcode.... Once completed it will install the app on Apple Watch.

Then, Apple watch app will launch and stuck on launching screen with "loading" spinner on the Apple Watch device.

[image]

The Apple watch will just close itself and this error will appear in Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the your iphone app scheme not the watchapp or extension scheme, once you will installed your iOS application on your device with watch kit support.

After installing the iPhone, you need to check your watch, application will automatically installed on Watch. If still you are not able to see the application then you need to visit application "Apple Watch" and scroll down to see your application and turn on apple watch support for your application.

Comment: Hi @deoKaushal, I'm already running the iPhone app scheme. The app os already installed on the watch. it's just that it just got stuck on the loading screen after launching and pops out that error....btw, on the simulator, I can just run the watchapp scheme. Why is it so?

Comment: Delete the app from your phone, try to clean and delete the derived data folder, then give a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the Watch OS2 app then after deploying the app on the Watch, you will need to reboot the Watch. Once rebooted, the Watch app will now run and not stuck anymore, loading time is about a few seconds only.

Comment: rebooting the watch does not help in my case